# complexification of maximal compact subgroup

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $K$ be a maximal compact subgroup of a Lie group $G$. Then $G/K$ is isomorphic to a Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$. Consider the complexification $G^\mathbb C$ and $K^\mathbb C$. Is true that $G^\mathbb C/K^\mathbb C$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C^m$?

Comment: what do you mean by "isomorphic"?

Comment: biholomorphic equivalent

Comment: not in your first sentence...

Comment: yes sure, the first is a diffeomorphism

Answer (score 2):

No. For $d\ge 2$, take $G=\mathrm{SL}_d(\mathbf{R})$ and $K=\mathrm{SO}_d(\mathbf{R})$. Then $G^{\mathbf{C}}/K^{\mathbf{C}}=\mathrm{SL}_d(\mathbf{C})/\mathrm{SO}_d(\mathbf{C})$.

But the latter is not contractible, hence not homeomorphic to any Euclidean space. This can be seen in various ways; one is from the exact sequence
$$\pi_2(H)\to\pi_2(H/L)\to\pi_1(L)\to\pi_1(H);$$
which for $H=\mathrm{SL}_d(\mathbf{C})$ and $L=\mathrm{SO}_d(\mathbf{C})$ yields, since both extreme terms vanish, an isomorphism $$\pi_2(\mathrm{SL}_d(\mathbf{C})/\mathrm{SO}_d(\mathbf{C}))\simeq\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
         \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z} & \mbox{for}
         & d\ge 3 \\ \mathbf{Z} & \mbox{for}
         & d=2.
                \end{array}\right.
$$

Comment: Thanks YCore! I am wondering now if $G$ was complex Lie group then $G/K^\mathbb C$ is contractible??

Comment: What do you mean? if $G$ is a complex Lie group then $K^{\mathbf{C}}=G$.

Comment: Why should it be? Maybe $G$ is not reductive !

Comment: in general complexification of a Lie group is not well-defined. But if you mean $G$ a real algebraic group, then $K^{\mathbf{C}}$ will be a Levi factor and the quotient will indeed be biholomorphic to the unipotent radical, and hence to some $\mathbf{C}^k$.